# Cant find if my office version is up to date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm having some trouble determining exactly which version of office is installed on a Windows server 2016.

For exemple in "Account" here

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzMF3.png)

nothing is chown

But when i go in "about word" i have a version

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG5cL.png)

According to this im in 16.0.4266.1001

So I want to know if the server is using the last office version

When im reffering to [microsoft website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date) they are using build number totally different to mine. How can I know what my office build is and if it is up to date ?

I have looked on many forums to find what my version was related to but I didn't find anything

Thank you a lot

Tristan

Comment: Can you use VBA? [There are ways to get version number](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-vba-to-return-the-current-version-number-of-any-office-application/) with `Application.Version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version number shows that you have a volume license, which means you don't get monthly updates. You only get quarterly or semi-annual security updates.

None of the new features available to Office 365 subscribers are provided in your version. If you want new features you must either subscribe to Office 365 or purchase a volume license to Office 2019 when that is released this month.

Here's a link about volume licenses [Security Updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4092447/description-of-the-security-update-for-word-2016-september-11-2018) and how to get them. It's a Microsoft article. All you need to do is a Check for Updates from Word.

Comment: I was looking to find if my office needed a security update or if its up to date. where can i know it ?

Comment: @user7394492, I've added a link to a Microsoft article on checking for security updates.

Comment: I have `16.0.4738.1000`, is it a volume license too? How do I know? Does it mean that I am stuck with Excel Javascript API 1.1?